# How to assign consecutive numbers to nodes of directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

There's a graph with a lot of nodes, and very few edges between them - the problem is assigning numbers to nodes, so that most nodes are from i to i+1 or otherwise close.

My problem is about printing graph data nicely, but an algorithm just like that is part of pretty much every compiler (intermediate code is just a graph, produced object code gets memory locations).

I thought it was just straightforward depth-first search, but results of that aren't that great - it seems to minimize number of links back well enough, but ones it leaves tend to be horrible (like 1 -> 500 -> 1).

Any better ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "so that most nodes are from i to i+1 or otherwise close."?

Comment: @Assaf: I would define it as tagging the N nodes of a graph with unique numbers from {1,2,...,N} so that the sum of deltas of all connected pairs it minimal. Is this correct?

Comment: this could be a very interesting problem if I could only understand what you mean... is it like a Hamiltonian path problem? "i to i+1" between as many nodes as possible?

Comment: i believe OP means "most edges are from node i to node i+1". Once we have that, though, how do you quantify "or otherwise close"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CCMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.ucsd.edu%2F~fan%2Fmypaps%2Ffanpap%2Ffc47problems.pdf&ei=Sm5DTKDPE4_GsAP7pf2UDQ&usg=AFQjCNGuAt3GZ0sN4i1cj5M2jDU3cT4kSQ&sig2=Pml2Rvy5RwrRBwr2c-Ny5g) discusses this problem, if you use Eyal Schneider's formulation of minimizing the sum of the edge deltas (absolute value of the difference between the endpoints' labels). It's under #2, Optimal Linear Arrangements.

Sadly, there's no algorithm given for achieving an optimal ordering (or labeling), and the general problem is NP-complete. There are references to some polynomial-time algorithms for trees, though.

If you want to get into the academic stuff, google gives lots of hits for "Optimal Linear Arrangements".